# A lot of TCP and UDP errors in Boring Man

Tags: steam, technical-issues, hosting, boring-man

I've been playing Boring Man (a free online shooter on Steam) for a while and a ton of errors keep flooding me every time I want to join a game.

**Common Errors:** `TCP Error 4`, `UDP Error 5`, `TCP Error 5`

I've asked other players in the game (when I can actually connect), and their error rate seems significantly lower than mine.

---

**What I've tried:**

- I've connected to a variety of servers and it appears that the community servers, hosted by players, are more likely to cause errors
- Restarting the game AND Steam (3 times!)
- Restarting my WiFi connection

I would really like some help on this pesky issue.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the threads about error codes in this particular game? Or maybe you can connect to the developers of this game about the issue, maybe they can help better.

Comment: Well, the game's site doesn't say much about reducing the errors.  But Update 1.7.1 has significantly reduced the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 1.7.1 seemed to reduce the error by *a lot*.  I guess it was some random bug in the game.